# BufferedImage into Android bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I've got a problem. I need to save a java `BufferedImage` object in an `String`. Convert this `String` on the `Android` application into `Bitmap`. How can I achieve this? Or maybe you can recommend me the other way to transfer image information in the `String` format.

```
public static String encodeToString(BufferedImage image, String type)          {
    String imageString = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);
        byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();
        imageString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageBytes);
        bos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       log.error("Can't encode to String");
    }
    return imageString;
}
```

Comment: why `String`?? cant you use `byte[]` ??

Comment: I need to save this String in xml format like a field.

Answer (score 1):

Base64 encoding and decoding of images using Java 8:

```
public static String imgToBase64String(final RenderedImage img, final String formatName) {
final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    ImageIO.write(img, formatName, Base64.getEncoder().wrap(os));
    return os.toString(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.name());
} catch (final IOException ioe) {
    throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
}
}

public static BufferedImage base64StringToImg(final String base64String) {
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String)));
    } catch (final IOException ioe) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
    }
}
```

hope so will work,
enjoy your code:)

Comment: @see http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/tools/layoutlib/bridge/src/android/graphics/Bitmap.java.shtml

Comment: BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(file);
Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bufferedImage, null);
myImageView.setImage(image);

Comment: You can't use BufferedImage in Android directly

Comment: yes,ImageIO is not supported in Android SDK, so you have to use Bitmap tgtImg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("ImageD2.jpg");

Comment: But I need to convert String into Bitmap not load image.